# Is it possible to crack WPA2 faster than brute-force? If yes, how?

Tags: authentication, network, brute-force, wpa2

Does WPA2 have any weaknesses, flaws or gaps that would make a hack faster than brute-force possible?

Maybe I can hijack authorized user's session or trick AP itp.

Comment: The obvious answer is to abuse WPS on a router which does not have rate limiting on WPS attempts, but as far as I'm aware WPA2 itself is not currently known to be vulnerable to anything but passphrase bruteforcing.